# repeat the code once and not to every element - .each method - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I have this little program which takes the text that a user types in, asks which word to redact and then redacts that word :

```
puts "Text to search through: "
text = gets.chomp
puts "Word to redact: "
redact = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |word|
  if word != redact
    print "no such word. "
  else
    print "REDACTED ! "
  end
end
```

However, I don't like the output since using .each method it gets repeated and doesn't look neat.

```
Text to search through: 
this is my text
Word to redact: 
is
no such word. REDACTED ! no such word. no such word.
```

What would be the solution to stop it repeating the answer for every element of array and print "REDACTED !" just once ?

Or when there's no word to redact, instead of repeating the answer to every element like so :

```
Text to search through: 
this is my text
Word to redact: 
no
no such word. no such word. no such word. no such word.
```

Print "No such word" just once. Thanks.

Comment: _"and then redacts that word"_ – your code just prints "REDACTED !" without actually changing the input.

Comment: actually you are right, it does not exactly what I want it to do

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#gsub-21-method) – the bang variant returns `nil` if no changes were made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array#include?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) method to check if words include redact:

```rb
if words.include?(redact)
  print "REDACTED !"  
else
  print "no such word."
end
```

Comment: ...or `print words.include?(redact) ? 'REDACTED !' : 'no such word'`.

Comment: But how do I make the output to be all words and just the word that needs to be changed is changed to a string "REDACTED !" ?  @eux

Comment: You could replace `redcat`  by `String#sub`: `text.sub(redcat, "REDCATED !")`